# How to receive data from this $.post

Tags: jquery

This code I want to receive data from `$.post("re.asp` . How do I do that?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function () {
  $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
    var $pastable = $(this);
    $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#target").html($pastable.val());
        $pastable.focus();
    }, 100);
  });});
 });
 </script>
 Paste here: <input id="pasteable" />
 <span id="target"></span>
```

Comment: No need to use the 'setTimeout' as the function() is called on complete. Include a callback var 'function (data) {...' and you'll recieve the data back after the call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$(function () {
   $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
   var $pastable = $(this);
   $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(data){
    alert(data);    //it will return your data(from re.asp) you can fetch from here
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you receive data from `$.post()`

```
$.post("URL", {name1:val1, name2:val2}, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

In the callback you need to pass the variable which will hold the result of the URL page

In your case

```
 $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(data){
    alert(data);  // data has the result of re.asp
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I can do it but i want to use this function **setTimeout(function () {
$("#target").html($pastable.val());
$pastable.focus();
}, 100); *too $.post i try but still error pastable undefined***
    <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function () {
   $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
    var $pastable = $(this);
    $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(){
     setTimeout(function () {
    $("#target").html($pastable.val());
    $pastable.focus();
    }, 100);
  });});
 });
  </script>
 Paste here: <input id="pasteable" />
  <span id="target"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st I recommend using jQuery. rather then $. if your going to be using variables with the $ symbol for your sanity depending how large the project is going to grow and 
2nd a setTimeout is not needed here. Being unaware of the performance hit and overusing selectors instead of assigning them to local variables.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function () {
  $("#pasteable").bind('paste', function (event) {
    pastable = $(this);
    $.post("re.asp",{ste:pastable},function(data){
        //data variable is your response from re.asp
        $("#target").html(pastable.val());
        pastable.focus();

    });
  });
 });
 </script>
 Paste here: <input id="pasteable" />
 <span id="target"></span>
```

now if your looking for json, html, xml, etc. specify like follows

```
$.post('',{},function(data){},  'json');
```

function(data){} where '**data**' is your response.hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just read documentation...

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

I hope you know how to use this information.

Comment: I think he's asking how to access the data returned by "example.php" not how to use the callbacks.